# pgrouting crashes and restarts the postgresql server when searching for endpoints in 2 disjoints graphs

Tags: pgrouting

I have

```
>apt-show-versions postgresql-9.1-pgrouting
postgresql-9.1-pgrouting/precise uptodate 2.0.0-release-ppa1~precise2
```

Whenever I do a search http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/astar/doc/index.html between two end points in disjoint graphs, I get  the error error sending I/O to backend and my postgresql server crashes and restarts. Why doesnt this simply return a no route found?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a bug report on the pgRouting issue tracker:
https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/245